# How to delete a nested array inside a main array and delete the whole array if the nested array is empty in MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, web

I am trying to delete a nested array inside a MongoDB array. now I can delete the single array from the nested array, but when the nested array is completely empty, I would want to delete the main array itself.

Below is my JSON structure

```html
1
    id : "5b76ae3a40c1c449d6409fa3"
    vendor_user_id : "5b17b992c440782b5a218cd2"
    product_type_id : "5ae8348b7ae0d9538e45ab46"
    condition_id
          0
            _id : "5ae977da7ff1706f3b7dc47a"
            status : 0
            date_added : "2018-08-17-11-15-06"    
          1
            _id : "5ae978187ff1706f3b7dc47c"
            status : 0
          date_added : "2018-08-17-11-15-06"
    shipping_cost : 100
```

Now if I have deleted ($pull) all the nested elements of `condition_id` i would want the main array to also get deleted.

Ps: I can delete individual elements so far but I cannot delete do both the tasks of deleting the nested elements and then checking if it's empty and if it's not then deleting the whole array

EDIT 1:
This is my main array . And i want to delete the array's inside `condition_id` based upon their id , and when the `condition_id` is empty i want to delete the corresponding array in which they are present

```html
  "product": [
    {
      "id": "5b71310eeff5c42f00f8a4e8",
      "vendor_user_id": "5b17b992c440782b5a218cd2",
      "product_type_id": "5ae834807ae0d9538e45ab45",
      "condition_id": [
        {
          "_id": "5ae977da7ff1706f3b7dc47a",
          "status": 1,
          "date_added": "2018-08-10-09-55-54"
        }
      ],
      "shipping_cost": "100",
      "date_added": "2018-08-10-09-55-54",
      "date_status_change": "2018-08-10-09-55-54",
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "5b76ae3a40c1c449d6409fa3",
      "vendor_user_id": "5b17b992c440782b5a218cd2",
      "product_type_id": "5ae8348b7ae0d9538e45ab46",
      "condition_id": [
        {
          "_id": "5ae977da7ff1706f3b7dc47a",
          "status": 0,
          "date_added": "2018-08-17-11-15-06"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5ae978187ff1706f3b7dc47c",
          "status": 0,
          "date_added": "2018-08-17-11-15-06"
        }
      ],
      "shipping_cost": 100,
      "date_added": "2018-08-17-11-15-06",
      "date_status_change": "2018-08-17-11-15-06",
      "status": 0
    },
    {
      "id": "5b76b41240c1c44d4d6e38f2",
      "vendor_user_id": "5b17b992c440782b5a218cd2",
      "product_type_id": "5ae834a67ae0d9538e45ab47",
      "condition_id": [
        {
          "_id": "5ae978587ff1706f3b7dc47e",
          "status": 0,
          "date_added": "2018-08-17-11-40-02"
        }
      ],
      "shipping_cost": 100,
      "date_added": "2018-08-17-11-40-02",
      "date_status_change": "2018-08-17-11-40-02",
      "status": 0
    }]
```

Comment: What do you mean by main array? do you want to delete `condition_id` field as well  when it is empty

Comment: `main array` means the array at the nth index . This is just a single instance of that array that i have posted above . so that the problem is clear to understand

Comment: yes . i want to delete whole array at the nth index if the `condition_id` field is empty.

Comment: I am trying to make . that if a product does not have a `condition` associated . then i have to delete that array

Comment: If there is no object inside `condition_id` then you want to delete that key from the database?

Comment: yes exactly . if the `condition_id` is empty then the main array of that corresponding index should also get deleted.

Comment: again you are confusing... ***main array of that corresponding index*** please explain this... Or post the sample output

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet i have updated my answer . and i have tried to clear out the confusion